# Punctuating when quoted fragment stands alone as complete sentence

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, quotations

What is the proper punctuation for quoting a fragment of a sentence when the omitted material is from both the beginning and the ending of the original sentence, yet the quoted fragment is still a complete sentence on its own?

Comment: That it is a complete sentence should make no difference. As it is a part of a longer sentence that extends on both sides, we may include ellipses appropriately. "... xxx xxx ...". May be depends on the applicable style guide as well, not sure about that part.